# Hangouts and Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-hangouts

So, after looking through many posts I've came to the conclusion that you can't invite anybody to a hangouts (video) chat through a custom app, but you may be able to send SMS.

I would like to know if it's actually true because some of the posts were quite old, so I'll tell you what I've tried.

I couldn't find a proper Intent to launch a Hangouts invitation on Android, and I would really like to find a way of doing so. What I've been able to do is launching Hangouts from a web browser

The code goes like this...

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : 'foo@example.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
</body>
```

The problem is that this only works from desktop browsers to Android phones.
If you try to launch it from an Android phone, Hangouts will pop up, but you'll get a NullPointerException if you try doing anything like writing a message, because the person invited (or the chat session created) is actually "null".